# JavaScript Function Not Returning Anything

Tags: javascript, return

I made a function that reduces two numbers with the relationship of fraction. It works perfectly but the problem is that it won't return the value. I've tried various things such as declaring a new variable and then returning it, but it won't work. I also added a couple console.logs to see if it was stopping at a certain spot but nothing, it's just not returning anything. 
Here's my code:

```
function reduceFraction(n, d) {
    var numerator = n;
    var denominator = d;

    if (n % 7 === 0 && d % 7 === 0) {
        numerator /= 7;
        denominator /= 7;
        console.log('Divided by 7');
        reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
    } else {
        if (n % 5 === 0 && d % 5 === 0) {
            numerator /= 5;
            denominator /= 5;
            console.log('Divided by 5');
            reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
        } else {
            if (n % 3 === 0 && d % 3 === 0) {
                numerator /= 3;
                denominator /= 3;
                console.log('Divided by 3');
                reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
            } else {
                if (n % 2 === 0 && d % 2 === 0) {
                    numerator /= 2;
                    denominator /= 2;
                    console.log('Divided by 2');
                    reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
                } else {
                    console.log('Was not divided by anything');
                    var reduced = numerator + "/" + denominator;
                    return reduced; //console.log(numerator + "/" + denominator); logs 1/18
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
reduceFraction(3, 54);
```

I don't know if nesting a bunch of if statements has to do anything with it but that's the only way (that I can think of) right now that it would reduce a fraction... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a recursive function, you need the `return` too :

Replace all the

```
    reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
```

like this :

```
    return reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to **return** it

```
 function reduceFraction(n, d) {
    var numerator = n;
    var denominator = d;

    if (n % 7 === 0 && d % 7 === 0) {
        numerator /= 7;
        denominator /= 7;
        console.log('Divided by 7');
        return reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
    } else {
        if (n % 5 === 0 && d % 5 === 0) {
            numerator /= 5;
            denominator /= 5;
            console.log('Divided by 5');
            return reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
        } else {
            if (n % 3 === 0 && d % 3 === 0) {
                numerator /= 3;
                denominator /= 3;
                console.log('Divided by 3');
                return reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
            } else {
                if (n % 2 === 0 && d % 2 === 0) {
                    numerator /= 2;
                    denominator /= 2;
                    console.log('Divided by 2');
                    return reduceFraction(numerator, denominator);
                } else {
                    console.log('Was not divided by anything');
                    var reduced = numerator + "/" + denominator;
                    return reduced; //console.log(numerator + "/" + denominator); logs 1/18
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return reduceFraction(3, 54);
```